# Change keyboard shortcuts in Firefox's "Pop-out video player"

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Firefox's pop-out video player is great for watching videos in the background, but I keep accidentally closing it.  I use a text editor that uses the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key a lot (i.e. like Vim) and sometimes when switching between windows I ends up on the video window before pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, causing it to close.

I was wondering if anyone had pointers into the easiest way to change this behavior.  I use the Sway window manager and thought I might be able to convince it to absorb those key presses but it doesn't look as easy as I was hoping.  Hints/suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Looking the source code which seems to be [behind this feature](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/rev/e9b338c2d597067f99e96d5f20769f41f312fa8f/toolkit/components/pictureinpicture/content/player.js#378) doesn't suggest an easy way to customise it :(

Answer (score 1):

I wrote some Python code to work around this from my window manager, Sway.  In case anybody else wants to do this I've created a [pull request in the `sway-contrib` repo](https://github.com/OctopusET/sway-contrib/pull/13).

Should then be a simple manner of adding:

```
exec python sway-contrib/firefox-focus-monitor.py
```

to your Sway config file.